# Moving apps to adoptable storage

Tags: adoptable-storage, resurrection-remix-os

[image]

In Resurrection Remix nugget rom i am not able to move some apps to adoptable storage . why ? Any solutions ?

Comment: Some info about adoptable storage https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170030/lineage-os-sd-card-as-internal-storage , https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162790/adaptive-internal-storage-analysis

Answer (score 1):

Guess what i found the solution.
Titanium backup pro lets you move the apps to adoptable storage of apps which system doesn't give option to .